# angularjs Click to Edit with validation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-validation

Im having a problem in my forms in validating empty fields. When the user clicked the edit button and clear the input field then click the send button, there is no validation that’s happening. I’ve tried angularjs’s form validation but it seems not working. Here’s the live view Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/920/

```
function ClickToEditCtrl($scope) {
$scope.name = "joe Doe";
$scope.email = "joe@yahoo.com";

$scope.enableEditor = function () {
    $scope.showEditor = true;
    $scope.editName = $scope.name;
    $scope.editEmail = $scope.email;

};

$scope.disableEditor = function () {
    $scope.showEditor = false;
};

$scope.saveEditor = function () {
    $scope.name = $scope.editName;
    $scope.email = $scope.editEmail;

    $scope.disableEditor();
};
```

}

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues with your fiddle.

Firstly the scope properties such as `studentForm.name.$dirty` for ngModelController used in submit is incorrect.

Each of your input should have `name` properties so that i can be referenced in code under form controller reference.

Secondly for ng-disable it should be button or input not div.

Lastly you can check the form state instead of all input state.

Please check my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/dxzeggtp/